# Can this be more concise?

Tags: expression-choice

How do I say this more concisely and more effectively in one sentence?

"The baseball and the basketball(s) should have the same shape, or the shape of the basketball(s) should be the same with the majority shape."

To make things clear, I don't know the majority shape yet. Also, "(s)" means I don't know whether there will be many or just one basketball made.

Comment: I think you have to tell first what the majority shape is. Is it pertaining to the majority shape of the balls (which is round)? What is your point here? What do you want to say?

Comment: Thanks for reading. No, majority shape doesn't pertain to round yet. I'm thinking of an instruction/luck game where participants will have to draw what they want the said balls' shapes to be. They have to draw one baseball and an unlimited number of basketballs. Majority shape is the most common shape that most participants will draw. Those who will follow the instruction correctly will score a point. I hopefully want to say the said instruction in a more correct but also more concise way.

Comment: Try writing it out in more words, rather than fewer words. Then maybe we can understand what you are asking. Until then...

Comment: Thanks Jim, how about this one? "The baseball and the basketball(s) you have drawn should have the same shape, or the shape of the basketball(s) you have drawn should be the same with the majority shape drawn among you and the other members' drawing boards." I excluded some of the words because the context is already known.

Comment: What is the reason for drawing one baseball with many basketballs? Presumably every basketball has to be identical, and the baseball much smaller. Do the participants have to draw freehand?

Comment: Well, it's a game involving creativity too. So, I thought, why not baseballs and basketballs. Yes, they have to draw freehand.

Answer (score 2):

It is a little hard to understand exactly what you are intending to convey. Would one of these work?

> Any baseballs or basketballs must match the shape of the most common shape.
>
> Any baseballs or basketballs should either (a) have the same shape or (b) match the majority shape.
>
> Any baseballs or basketballs drawn should match the shape that was drawn the most.

Comment: Thanks MrHen, the second one is close. Although in the case when basketballs exhibit the majority shape, the baseball can have a different shape from the basketballs or from the majority shape. I'll try to give you +1 once I get able.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a game you have to make it challenging and engaging. Therefore you need to set out the rules clearly, be precise with numbers and perhaps model the task first so that everybody understands what they have to do.

> Draw one baseball and nine basketballs. They should all be the same
>   shape but the basketballs have to be *exactly* the same size. The person
>   who draws the most number of identically sized basketballs is the winner.

I think saying that the baseball can be a different shape from the basketball is inviting confusion. Aren't all basketballs and baseballs simply round?